Sum does not work on fraction

As shown in the code above, Sum does not work in the second case, where denominator differs from numerator by 2. Adding assumptions (n>0, d>0) or using Simplify or FullSimplify inside or outside Sum does not help. Is there a way around this? Adding assumptions?

Please show us the code text rather than a screenshot of it.

Sum[Simplify[(1/2+n)^(2 d)/(1+2 n)^8/.n->(m-1)/2]/.m->2n+1,{n,-∞,∞}]


What you have to realize -I think- is that you have to help Mathematica to re-express the denominator as the numerator times a number. Then you can perform the sum. It is done in the following way:
With
eq = (1/2 + n)^(2 d)/(1 + 2 n)^8;

run the following
FullSimplify@
 PowerExpand[
  Numerator[
     eq]/((xx /. 
        Flatten[Factor[
          Solve[Denominator[
             eq] == (Numerator[eq] /. 
                Flatten[Solve[Exponent[Numerator[eq], n] == 1]])^
              Exponent[Denominator[eq], n] xx, xx]]]) (Numerator[
          eq] /. Flatten[Solve[Exponent[Numerator[eq], n] == 1]])^
       Exponent[Denominator[eq], n]) // 
   Sum[#, {n, -Infinity, Infinity}] &]

